# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: php, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I am new to Blockchain. I want to call a function to read a variable from contract. My contract

```php
$result = $contractInstance->send('insert_candidates_Information',$seat, ['122aa'],['$candpic'],['$parties'],
                ['$partylogo'],$param,function ($error, $result) use ($contractInstance){
                if ($error !== null) {
                    echo "Error: " . $error->getMessage();
                    echo "Result: ". $result;
                    // Get the full error message
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "Error Trace: " . $error->getTraceAsString();
                }
                else
#               {
                    $result = $contractInstance->call('check_information', function ($error, $result){
                        if ($error !== null) {
                            echo "Error: " . $error->getMessage();
                            echo "Error: " . $error->getMessage();
                            // Get the full error message
                            echo "<br>";
                            echo "Error Trace: " . $error->getTraceAsString();
                        }
                        else if ($result[0]) {
                            header("location: http://localhost/Votedo/new-cand-form.php");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">';
                            echo 'candidates not inserted';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

### Error coming

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revertResult:
Error Trace: #0 E:\Software\xamp\htdocs\Votedo\vendor\sc0vu\web3.php\src\Providers\HttpProvider.php(62): Web3\RequestManagers\HttpRequestManager->sendPayload('{"id":503686486...', Object(Closure)) #1 E:\Software\xamp\htdocs\Votedo\vendor\sc0vu\web3.php\src\Eth.php(105): Web3\Providers\HttpProvider->send(Object(Web3\Methods\Eth\SendTransaction), Object(Closure)) #2 E:\Software\xamp\htdocs\Votedo\vendor\sc0vu\web3.php\src\Contract.php(572): Web3\Eth->__call('sendTransaction', Array) #3 E:\Software\xamp\htdocs\Votedo\candedit.php(194): Web3\Contract->send('insert_candidat...', 'NA236', Array, Array, Array, Array, Array, Object(Closure)) #4 {main}
```

### My Smart contract Function

```
 function insert_candidates_Information(string memory seat,string[] memory cand_name,string[] memory cand_image,string[] memory party_name,string[] memory election_sign) public returns(bool){
        if(election_Date_Not_set() && access){
            if(!hasTimePassedPKT(startTime.Year,startTime.Month,startTime.Day,startTime.Hour,startTime.Minute)){
                (string[] memory _namePlusparty) = glue_candname_partyname(seat,cand_name,party_name);
                (string[] memory _cand_key) = check_candkey_Char(_namePlusparty);
                insert_Party_Information(party_name);
                for(uint i=0; i < cand_name.length; i++){
                    name_party_vote[_cand_key[i]] = Candidate(cand_name[i],cand_image[i],party_name[i],election_sign[i],0);
                    name_party_vote_record.push(_cand_key[i]);
                }
                if(!seat_Already_Exist(seat)){
                    seat_wise_candidates[seat] = _cand_key;
                    seat_wise_candidates_record.push(seat);
                    seats[seat] = true;
                }else{
                    for(uint i=0; i < cand_name.length; i++){
                        seat_wise_candidates[seat].push(_cand_key[i]);
                    }
                }
                information = true;
                return true;
            }
            information = false;
            return false;
        }
        information = false;
        return false;
    }
```

Invoking smart contract function and trying to insert data to smart contract